# webpack: inject javascript hashed file name in pug template

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, pug

I'm using pug as my Node.JS view engine.

And I'm bundling my javascript files using webpack with hashname for cache busting.

The problem here is that I don't know how to include the bundled javascript file name in my pug template because every time it generates a new hash name.

How can I get the hash name generated from webpack and include it in my pug file?

This is how it should include the script file:

```js
doctype html
html
  include _head

  body

    script(src='/_bundle/main.649c4c4e6c8076189257.js')
```

My webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require("path")
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: "./src/_public/js/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "main.[contenthash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/_public/_bundle"),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
       filetype: "pug",
     }),
     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
       filename: "./src/views/base.pug",
     }),
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure `HtmlWebpackPlugin` and `HtmlWebpackPugPlugin` properly:

```
const path = require("path")
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")
const HtmlWebpackPugPlugin = require('html-webpack-pug-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: "production",
    entry: "./src/_public/js/index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "main.[contenthash].js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/_public/_bundle"),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader",
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPugPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/views/base.pug',
            filename: 'layout.pug',
        }),
    ],
}
```

Install `npm i HtmlWebpackPugPlugin`. You will find the js and css references in the `layout.pug` file.

Answer (score 0):

Actual solution for 2022.

Install the [pug-plugin](https://github.com/webdiscus/pug-plugin):

```
npm i -D pug-plugin
```

Using the pug-plugin:

- the Webpack entry-point is the Pug file
- all source scripts (JS/TS) can be loaded via require() in Pug
- all source styles (CSS/SCSS) can be loaded via require() in Pug

Webpack config for Pug + JS + SCSS:

```js
const path = require('path');
const PugPlugin = require('pug-plugin');

module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/'),
    filename: 'js/[name].[contenthash:8].js' // output hashed filename of JS
  },

  entry: {
    // define Pug files in entry:
    index: './src/views/index.pug',      // => index.html
    about: './src/views/about/index.pug' // => about.html
    // ...
  },

  plugins: [
    // enable using Pug files as entry point
    new PugPlugin({
      extractCss: {
        filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash:8].css' // output hashed filename of CSS
      },
    })
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        loader: PugPlugin.loader, // the Pug loader
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
        use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Pug file *./src/views/index.pug*:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    //- load source styles via require()
    link(href=require('./path/to/scss/styles.scss') rel='stylesheet')
  body
    h1 Hello Pug!

    //- load source scripts via require()
    script(src=require('./path/to/js/index.js'))
```

Generated HTML:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="/css/styles.f57966f4.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello Pug!</h1>
    <script src="/js/index.b855d8f4.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```